# Laravel Notifications Event Listener Undefined Property

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the following error:

> Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent::$user in
>   /var/www/app/app/Listeners/NoticationListener.php:31

The error occurs here:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class NoticationListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  NotificationSent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(NotificationSent $event)
    {
       $notification = $event->notifiable;
       $addressee = $notification; //error here
       $address = $notification; 
       $type = "Notification";
       dispatch(new SendEmail($type,$addressee,$address));
    }
}
```

I don't understand this undefined property, especially on this line. How can I `dd()` from here? I tried to log the `$event` but I couldn't get it to log, only got this error.

My notifications work very well in the application, I just want an email to accompany them, which is why I have this event-listener/job.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

The repository code that is dispatching the notification is below:

```
public function notify($asset)
{
    $users = User::where("id","!=",Auth::user()->id)->get();
    Notification::send($users, new NewAsset($asset));
}
```

That extension of the `Notification` class is below:

```
class NewAsset extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $asset;

    public function __construct($asset)
    {
        $this->asset = $asset;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'asset_id' => $this->asset->id
        ];
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

If someone could advise how to do some error checking at this juncture, that could be helpful going forward. Because the code is async on the server it isn't returning data to the client, and when I try to get it to `Log` it doesn't seem to do so before it gets caught in the error.

How can I go about debugging in this scenario?

I've looked at the framework's [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bd352a0d2ca93775fce8ef02365b03fc4fb8cbb0/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Events/NotificationSent.php) and have no idea where the $user property is coming from. I assume it has to do with `$event->notifiable` being tied to the `User` model, but if it fires correctly for all affected users from within the application, why would its property be `undefined` in this context?

Please assist, thank you.

Comment: Can you show us your NotificationSent event?

Comment: @EduardoPacios it is framework code - see here (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bd352a0d2ca93775fce8ef02365b03fc4fb8cbb0/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Events/NotificationSent.php)

Comment: i run this notification class & work as well , if you not using  Notifiable trait on user throw exception like this : BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::routeNotificationFor()  , but your error is Must wonderfull , please set queue on sync and test value of $event

Comment: you can use via mail on all notifications class and implement method toMail() ; on every notification you can use a another implemention of sending mail , some view , text and ....

Comment: I can only guess, but it looks to me like the `SendMail` constructor tries to access `$arg2->user` where the property is actually `$arg2->users`.

Comment: For debugging your queue with `dd()` you need to setup queue driver  as sync in `.env` => **QUEUE_DRIVER=sync**.

Comment: You might try stop implementing ShouldQueue in the NotificationListener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a strange issue. As you found yourself, Laravel doesn't set a `$user`   property on that object itself, so something else must be involved. Here's my   understanding of the process:

1. `Notification::send()` → enqueue `NewAsset` notification for each user
2. Dequeue internal job for `NewAsset` notification → send notifications
3. Fire `NotificationSent` event → enqueue `NotificationListener` handler

*Error seems to occur here:*

4. Dequeue internal job for `NotificationListener` handler → handle event
5. Dispatch job for `SendEmail` [→ enqueue if `ShouldQueue`]
6. [Dequeue job for `SendEmail` if `ShouldQueue` →] Send notification email

As you can see, there's a lot of serialization and deserialization going on     when enqueueing and dequeueing the jobs for the notification. It seems like     the framework is trying to set the `$user` property when deserializing the      the `NotificationSent` event from the queue, but it's hard to tell from your    question without a full stack trace, and I'm not sure what adds `$user` to      the serialized data without more visibility into the code.

Here are some debugging suggestions to try:

**Restart the queue worker:**

After a queue worker starts, the PHP process doesn't reload changes to the source code from disk if the autoloader already imported the file. It seems possible that someone added the `$user` property to an object but didn't restart the worker, so it never picked up the change. During development, we need to restart the queue workers whenever the code changes for a queueable item. When deploying to production, it's a good idea to restart queue workers as part of the deployment process.

Alternatively, use the `artisan queue:listen` command instead of `queue:work` during development. This mode restarts the entire framework for each job.

**Set `QUEUE_DRIVER` to `sync`:**

This prevents the framework's event system from serializing the event data. If  the notification email sends without any errors, then we know that custom code  somewhere is adding a `$user` property to the event.

**Check serialized queue data:**

It's not clear from the question which queue driver your app uses. If you're    *not* using `sync`, we can look at the pending jobs in the queue to try to find   the discrepancy (in the database, Redis, etc).

1. Stop all queue workers.
2. Trigger the notification through the app.
3. Run `php artisan queue:work --once` to manually process one job until the   queued job runs and fires the `NotificationSent` event.
4. Inspect the job created in the queue to handle the `NotificationSent` event

We can also use this approach to dump data using `dd()` during queue jobs       because `artisan queue:work --once` runs in the foreground.

**Don't enqueue the `NotificationSent` event handler**:

Because the notification is already configured to process in a queued background job, we don't necessarily need to enqueue the notification event handler as well. Try removing the `ShouldQueue` interface to see if this resolves the problem.

As other commenters mentioned, this problem may be better solved using Laravel's [Mail Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#mail-notifications) which remove the need for a separate `NotificationSent` event handler entirely.